# Elastic Beanstalk Workers and the VisibilityTimeout period

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

According to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html:

```
If the application returns any response other than 200 OK, then Elastic
Beanstalk waits to put the message back in the queue after the configured
VisibilityTimeout period.
```

I have set the VisibilityTimeout to 1 minute. My app is returning a 400 error when processing the request. I see from the logs that the request is being re-tried every 2 seconds! I was expecting, based on the above, for it to retry every 60 seconds.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be the issue of the SQS queue at all. It is true that the message is returned to the queue only after the specified **VisibilityTimeout**, but it depends on how you are polling the messages.

If you do not access the queue directly (but use some kind of service to do it for you), you have another layer of complexity there.

There's a worker process in Elastic Beanstalk called `sqsd` that's doing the polling, (processing the messages and deleting them from the queue once you respond with 200).

The `sqsd` uses similar concept called **InactivityTimeout** - this specifies the time for this worker to wait for the 200 response and it resends the message after this time if such response is not delivered.

My guess is that the cause of your problem is in this InactivtyTimeout.

If this is not the cause, try looking into the `WaitTimeSeconds` parameter of your SQS. This specifies that the call to the SQS should be returned immediately if there are messages in the queue (otherwise, it waits for the specified time).

I had a similar issue with an EC2 instance and I specified all the timeouts. In the end - it turned it was caused by a bug in Tomcat - see this: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=183473

Comment: I found the Inactivity Timeout setting, under Advanced Options. It is set to 299 seconds.

Comment: There is an "Error Visibility Timeout", and it is set to 2 seconds. I'll change that and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, let me know how it goes. I was solving a similar issue lately.

Comment: Yes, changing that value gave me the result I was expecting! Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction!